# Switch goes to default case even though other cases match

Tags: java

I know the answer for this question is -1, but I do not understand why it is. Can someone help me figure it out?

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

switch (x + 1)  {
  case 0: y = 0; 
  case 1: y = 1;
  default: y = -1
}
```

Comment: Your debugger can

Comment: There is no break statement after every case statement

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to `break`, so all your matched cases "fall through":

You need this instead:

```
switch (x + 1)  {
case 0: y = 0; break;
               ^^^^^
case 1: y = 1; break;
               ^^^^^
default: y = -1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation

Because even if `case` condition matches it doesn't exit the `switch` after executing the block but goes to next `case` (and `default`matches all conditions), so you should use `break` statement.

### Demonstration

```
//here y is 0
switch (x + 1)  {
  case 0: y = 0; //skipped because x+1 == 1
  case 1: y = 1; //executed, y now is 1
  default: y = -1; //matches all conditions, so after the previous one this one is executed and y is -1 now
}
```

### Solution

```
switch (x + 1)  {
  case 0: y = 0; break; //skipped because x+1 == 1
  case 1: y = 1; break; //executed, y now is 1 and we exit from switch because of break statement
  default: y = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `break`s after each case.

Try:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
switch (x + 1)  {
case 0: y = 0; break;
case 1: y = 1; break;
default: y = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no break statement so when a case matches then all the statements after that case are being executed .

[**Read here about switch case in detail**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (x + 1)  {
```

In this case `x + 1` is 1, so the switch jumps to `case 1` and sets y to 1. Since you don't have a `break` statement after `y = 1`, the code falls through to the next line which sets `y` to `-1`